# Add code to both iOS/objective-C project and c++ library at once?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, xcode

I have a usual Objective-C project and MonkSVG li which contains C++ classes.

I want to add some common functions/methods which I could use in both Objective-C and C++ code (for example work with regular expressions). But I don't want to import C++ and .mm classes because for example Xcode doesn't support refactoring in such code.

Currently I duplicate the same functions in both Objective-C and C++ code. Potentially I could write these classes in ANSI C code and extend MonkSVG library, but this language is too limited in comparison with Objective-C and C++.

So are there better ways to resolve this issue?

Comment: No, you have to use C from both C++ and Objective-C.  Mass-renaming of `.m` files to `.mm` doesn't difficult to me, though.

Comment: C is not "too limited". It's Turing-complete, and you can write object-oriented code in it. You can always write your code in C then create C++ and Objective-C wrappers around it. Also, you can opt to write your library in C++, then use Objective-C++ to call it from Objective-C. A third option would be to write your library in C++ and export some C bindings, but that's just insane (albeit possible, and - unfortunately - often done).

Comment: You didn't read the question intently. Rename .m to .mm, add some c++ code and try to refactor this code. I mean inner xCode "refactor" command

Comment: to H2CO3, C++ means "C with classes". C supports structures only. But can't I do vice versa? I mean for example write an objective-C code and ANSI C wrappers (.h files) for them which will be available from both objective-C and C++ code?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use [Objective-C++](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectiveC.html) (`.mm` files) you'd have to go down to the next common level:

**Plain C code.**

If you're simplied worried about not having refactoring in Xcode for Objective-C++ code you could still use Xcode and at the same time edit your code in something like AppCode.
It understands Xcode project files and does all the refactoring you could want.

Comment: thanks for advice with AppCode. Maybe I'll try it. But are there no ideas for example to create a separate library with code and link it to both MonkSVG and main project?